# Is it possible to create /sub/sub domain based multiste?

Tags: multisite

I've created multi-network with /sub url and it is working fine. And when I tried to add /sub/sub path it is not working. Is there a good tutorial available for this?

Comment: What have you alredy tried? What have you searched on Google?

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial/manual page will help you:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Before_You_Create_A_Network

See "Types of multisite network".